# Groupby and find difference from min value of group : Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a group like following, how can I know the difference of every observation with it's group minimum value

```
GROUP VALUE
 1     5
 2     2
 1     10
 2     20
 1     7
```

So, my desired output should be like

```
GROUP VALUE diff
 1     5    3
 2     2    0
 1     10   5
 2     20  18
 1     7    5
```

How can I achieve it with the help of pandas

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with subtract:

```
df['diff'] = df['VALUE'] - df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].transform('min')
print (df)
   GROUP  VALUE  diff
0      1      5     0
1      2      2     0
2      1     10     5
3      2     20    18
4      1      7     2
```

Comment: Can transform help to create two columns, if my function gives two output

Comment: @ManuSharma - Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael- Just posted the question with details